# Building OpenJDK 1.6u29 or later for Cipher Suite Override

Tags: java

To avoid Poodle Security issue, our Tomcat server must use RC4 as a #1 priority cipher. However, it looks like there is no simple way to make this happen in JDK 1.6 or later platform. I have to override other Cipher Suites with RC4 since we have a device setting to turn RC4 on in the client side.

I figured out that modifying the below source code from jsse.jar and patching it back would help me override the cipher suite.

Serverhandshaker.java (original source code)

```
private void chooseCipherSuite(ClientHello mesg) throws IOException {
    for (CipherSuite suite : mesg.getCipherSuites().collection()) {
        if (isNegotiable(suite) == false) {
            continue;
        }

        if (doClientAuth == SSLEngineImpl.clauth_required) {
            if ((suite.keyExchange == K_DH_ANON) ||
                (suite.keyExchange == K_ECDH_ANON)) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (trySetCipherSuite(suite) == false) {
            continue;
        }
        return;
    }
    fatalSE(Alerts.alert_handshake_failure,
                "no cipher suites in common");
}
```

Code to be modified:

```
/*
 * Choose cipher suite from among those supported by client. Sets
 * the cipherSuite and keyExchange variables.
 */
private void chooseCipherSuite(ClientHello mesg) throws IOException {
    for (CipherSuite suite : mesg.getCipherSuites().collection()) {

        ***final String RC4 = "SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA";
        if (RC4.equals(quite.toString()) == false){
            continue
        }***

        if (isNegotiable(suite) == false) {
            continue;
        }

        if (doClientAuth == SSLEngineImpl.clauth_required) {
            if ((suite.keyExchange == K_DH_ANON) ||
                (suite.keyExchange == K_ECDH_ANON)) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (trySetCipherSuite(suite) == false) {
            continue;
        }
        return;
    }
    fatalSE(Alerts.alert_handshake_failure,
                "no cipher suites in common");
}
```

Following are my road blocks,

1) JDK 6u29 is my running JRE. I am not able to locate ServerHandshaker.java in src.zip. I located the compiled class in jsse.jar. Where can I locate the source code that eventually builds into jsse.jar

2) According to the spec, ServerHandshaker.java is present in com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ServerHandshaker (JDK 6) but I am unable to locate the same.

3) After locating one, how can I create a patch of the modified file and integrate it back with jsse.jar

4) My environment is Windows 7 x64. Although, I am able to download Windows versions of OpenJDK 7 Source bundles, I am unable to find the bundles for 6 (any update).

I ran through a lot of googling but I could'nt find anything concrete. The pieces are disintegrated.

If there is a better way to override the cipher suite other than modifying the source code? kindly guide me through.